# random nr gen python (title isnt working constantly)

Tags: python

So I am pretty new to Python and to coding in general and I am trying to make a random number generator which makes a list of what numbers havent been displayed yet and doesnt repeat any of the numbers that have been displayed.

Thanks if someone wants to help me with this!

code:

`random.randrange(1, 50, 1) for i in range(7)`

`print ("number list is : " + str(res))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

lst = []

while len(lst) < 49:

    res = random.randrange(1, 50, 1)

    if res not in lst:

        print ("number list is : " + str(res))
        lst.append(res)
```

Here, you create a list `lst` and set your code in a `while` loop which focus on the length of `lst`. As the max of different number you can get is 49, you will stop getting random number once this condition is reached.

If your number `res` is not in `lst`, you print and append `res` to `lst`. If it is in `lst`, you just don't mention anything and loop again to the next "new" number.

Comment: tysm for the help, i think i get it now and so does my friend who failed helping me!!!

Comment: great :). If that's ok for this question you can think about accepting the answer ;) (gray tick top left or it). Thanks!